# Logging emails in SharePoint list

Tags: email, list

We have a requirement on a project that the client would like to see all correspondence between them and their customers in a central location.

We though of using a sharepoint list. What is then the best way to get the emails into the sharepoint list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to make it easy for users to store email in SharePoint. One way is to enable incoming email. The article [Configure incoming e-mail (SharePoint Server 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262947.aspx) on TechNet covers this in detail. This involves some environmental changes to setup email addresses that will be routed to your SharePoint server (e.g. Active Directory and/or Exchange) as well as configuring settings for the individual lists - the list settings are covered in the article [Enable and configure e-mail support for a list or library](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/help/HA100823071033.aspx). This works with both SharePoint 2007 and SharePoint 2010.

As you tagged the question with SharePoint 2010 an alternative would be to use SharePoint Workspace to allow users to drag and drop email from Outlook directly into the appropriate list or library but this does require licenses for Office 2010 or SharePoint Workspace 2010. Alternatively products such as [Colligo](http://colligo.com/products/sharepoint/contributor_uploader.asp) provide this type of functionality for SharePoint 2007.

Answer (score 3):

You can enable email on the list directly. The following comes directly from [Ken Zheng's post on this subject](http://littletalk.wordpress.com/2008/04/23/how-to-enable-incoming-email-to-a-sharepoint-list-or-library/).

> SharePoint users can add content to
>   discussion boards, announcements,
>   calendars, libraries (document,
>   picture and form) and blogs via email.
>   By setting your list or library up to
>   receive email, you can efficiently
>   update the content of your site
>   without having to navigate the
>   SharePoint frontend.
>
> - Login to your SharePoint site.
> - Navigate to the list or document library you want to email to.
> - Click Settings.
> - Choose List Settings or Document Library Settings respectively.
> - In the far right column, select Incoming Email Settings.
> - Click Yes to allow items to be added through email and create an
>     email address to which you will send
>     the items.
> - OPTIONAL: You can modify other Incoming Email Settings regarding
>     attachments, messages, meeting
>     invitations and security on this page,
>     as well.
> - When finished, click OK to complete the setup. Incoming email has now been
>     enabled for your SharePoint list or
>     library.

[More posts on this subject](http://www.google.co.uk/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=sharepoint+email+to+list).

Answer (score 1):

Custom list cannot receive incoming emails unless you use some tool like http://anurasoftware.com/default.aspx